# How to find configuration files?

Tags: filesystem

I know that the /etc folder handles different configuration files, but how does one know where the configuration files of a service (iscsi target for example) are located ?

Comment: `find /etc -iname "*iscsi*"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You open the manual page for the command or service you want it for. The conf file for iscsi is [iscsi.conf](http://linux-iscsi.sourceforge.net/iscsi.conf.5.html)

I tend to assume a conf file will have {service/application}.conf. Most applications I use have something like that (with MySQL as the exception ;) )

Comment: other is for sshd `sshd_config` and more, who knows

Answer (score 11):

You will just have to find the name of package particular service comes from `dpkg -S <Any file you know and think comes from that package which provided the service>`

```
cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.conffiles
```

This will help.

Comment: I like yours more than mine ;=)

Comment: @Rinzwind Just joined today, so appreciate this comment. Thanks!