# How do I uninstall IPFS completely from Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, uninstall, software-uninstall

To give a good picture of my problem I am going to illustrate that using the sequence of installations I have done :

1. I downloaded ipfs from the link available on their [official website](https://dist.ipfs.io/#go-ipfs)
   . This is ipfs-go which I was supposed to download for my Ubuntu OS.
2. To install the tar.gz file I followed the method under the section [Installing from a Prebuilt Package for MacOS and Linux](https://ipfs.io/docs/install/)
3. I later tried to uninstall it by following up the SO threads, but to no avail.

[What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118022/how-do-i-unpin-and-remove-all-ipfs-content-from-my-machine

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43118022/how-do-i-unpin-and-remove-all-ipfs-content-from-my-machine

4. Later I came across [IPFS desktop version](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-desktop/releases) with an intent to uninstall IPFS through [GUI method](https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-desktop#install) but it shows some error while installing although the icon can be seen on my applications menu.
5. Now I have to uninstall the **IPFS GUI** and the **ipfs** present on my system and I cannot figure out a way.

Please see the screenshots below to understand the problem with IPFS GUI (It cannot be uninstalled when I go to ubuntu software center):
IPFS GUI application [does not appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqCZ6.png) in the software center

Please answer my problem in a two-part form which uninstalls **ipfs** and **ipfs gui** completely from my system. I have searched for the solution online but I suppose there is no clear answer. Your help is very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem is Downloading and installing **Synaptic Package manager** from **Ubuntu software center**.

**`For removing IPFS GUI`**

1.Open `Synaptics Package Manager`

2.In the `Sections` tab select `All` and then type `ipfs` in the package tab. This will automatically search the `ipfs-desktop` package you installed using the .deb file.

3.Now right click and select `Mark for Removal`.

4.`Apply` the operations and wait. Synaptic Package manager will take care of the rest.

**`To remove IPFS`**

Just delete the ipfs files in `/home/.config`
To confirm that ipfs is removed check it by typing `ipfs` in the `Terminal`

**`Remove all the dependencies`**

In the end remove all the dependencies by

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Here are some other ULTIMATE useful links which explains in-depth on how to remove a software not present in Ubuntu Software Application Center but still appearing in Applications Menu

1.[In-depth and stepwise illustration to completely remove a package/software installed](https://complete-concrete-concise.com/ubuntu-2/ubuntu-13-04/ubuntu-13-04-how-to-completely-uninstallremove-a-packagesoftwareprogram)  (I have personally bookmarked this website as this is the ultimate solution to all your problems of uninstalling packages/software  )

2.Read the accepted answer on how to remove persistent config data from apt

3.How to find [configuration files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463356/how-to-find-configuration-files) in your system.